# Optional function parameter indication in UML Sequence Diagram

Tags: uml, notation, sequence-diagram

Is there any **formal** way to signal that a function parameter is optional?

For example, in this image:[image: in this image]

I want to inform that the `nodes_clicked` parameter could be populated or left empty.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm struggling with the same issue in 2021. Maybe you can do something like this, but i don't know if it is correct. Maybe someone else can confirm:

`get_data(columns_selected, <<opt>>nodes_clicked)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optional parameters are nothing handled in UML as it's jus "syntactic sugar" compilers implement to make coders happy. You can mimic that in a SD with a note attached to the message. However, I just would not go to that detail and leave it to the coder (they aren't children you have to tell each single step to take).

Answer (score 1):

Sequence diagrams represent sequence of function calls. Each messages calls functions with their parameters and the values of these parameters. So you can not model the fact that a parameter can have a value or another...

Comment: In the norm, a message maybe linked to an operation ( i did not find how but if the message is a synchronous call, this is an operation ) and operation may have optional parameter. So if you want to model that a message may have optional parameter, as Red Beard said you can't but you can link your message to an operation that have optional parameters.